# PostgreSQL, Update from Insert into sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 db, I have to update a table called "my_table" from db 1 to db 2.

Is there a way to dump the table from db1 and use that sql to update the table on the db2?

All I have is a sql file with `INSERT INTO` but I need an `UPDATE`

How could I do it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using (`MySQL`, `Postgres`, etc)?  When you say from "db 1 to db 2" do you mean you have two physical DB servers or just two tables stored in different databases on the same physical server?  Can you please post more information: your `INSERT INTO` statement, `DDL`, etc.

Comment: PostgreSQL, 2 different databases, different servers

Comment: If the data in those tables is so closely related, then why do you have two databases and not two schemas?

Comment: You can use foreign tables for that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that question as a very long and corporative answer... it's not my db, different countries, etc.

Comment: Using foreign tables to access remote tables directly might make the update obsolete to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using DB link:** dblink executes a query (usually a SELECT, but it can be any SQL statement that returns rows) in a remote database.

you can refer this official link(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) for DB link creation